# Showing the popup message or progress bar in nodejs while executing the exe

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have invoked the child_process to run the exe through nodejs using the below code.

```
exec('C:/Diva/bin/validation.exe', [path, validationPath, fileName], function(err, data) {

      if (err) {
        alert("Error message " +err);
      }else{
        //block of statements to proceed after the successful execution
      }
}
```

While executing the exe it takes some time to render the response. I want to show the some notification or progress bar until the execution completion process.

I'm in beginner level for nodejs. I could not figure out the solution to fix it.

Could anyone provide me the solution to accomplish it.

Thanks in advance,
Diva

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a loading animation in your terminal while the exe is being executed, then I'd suggest using either a npm package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/loading-spinner or coding your own animation with process.stdout.write

Comment: I'm not exactly looking for spinner. I'm invoking the child process to run some exe on background when i click on the button. I just wanna show the pop up message  or alert to let the user wait until the background process get finished. Hope you can see my code in post

Comment: wait, so it isn't a console application, but a web application? in that case I'm going to assume that you are sending a http request from the frontend to the backend to execute that exe. you could just respond to the request once the execution is finished and the frontend would be able to show an alert. either way I'm going to need more code to determine a good answer

Comment: It's like a console application. I'm using tinymce editor with electronjs. I have the nodejs script for running the process. When the user clicks on the tinymce custom button i will execute the exe. I just want to show the pop message like alert box until the process get executed. If it is web based application i can get the response in success call make the process to wait.

Comment: oh, I don't know anything about tinymce, I edited your question to add the tinymce tag, maybe someone else can help you